# Convergence of the sequence $\frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)}{\ln(n)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the limit of the following sequence
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)}{\ln n}$$
I have tried to use L'Hospitals rule but that did not work.  Any pointers of methods to try or estimates to consider will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Taylor expansion of $n^{1/n} = \exp \left(\frac{\log n}{n}\right)$ helps.

Comment: Yes, this helped me figure it out.  I thought about using the identity $\displaystyle x=e^{\ln x}$ for the whole sequence but not that part.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. This is $$\frac{e^{x_n} - 1}{x_n}$$ where $$x_n = \frac{\ln n}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$n^{1/n}-1=\exp\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)-1\sim\frac{\ln n}{n}$$
so we see easily that the desired limit is $1$.

**Edit** By writing $n^{1/n}-1\sim\frac{\ln n}n$ we mean that we neglect  terms of the Taylor expansion which haven't a contribution in the final result. In fact we have

$$n^{1/n}-1=\frac{\ln n}{n}+o\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$$
so
 $$\frac{n(n^{1/n}-1)}{\ln n}=1+o(1)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$$

Comment: This doesn't prove anything. You are ignoring terms of the Taylor expansion that could be divergent.

Comment: I edited my answer and I hope that's now clear for you!

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\dfrac{n}{\ln n} = \dfrac{1}{\ln n^{\frac{1}{n}}}$

Use that and the substitution $u = n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ If $n \to \infty$, $u\to 1$, then:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{n(n^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}{\ln n} = \lim_{u \to 1} \dfrac{u-1}{\ln u}$$ which is a known limit (You can use L'Hopital from here if you want to)